# Homogeneous systems Constant Coefficients Initial Value Problem with Eigenvalue of zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered the following problem involving a homogeneous system of constant coefficients initial value problem, but after determining one of the eigenvalues to be zero, I am not sure how to proceed to find the general solution.
$$
\frac {dx}{dt}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        20 & -20 \\
        5 & -5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}x\\
x(0)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -24 \\
        -9 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
The answer that I have come up with so far is as follows:
$$
\
x(t)=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -56e^{15t}+5\\
        -14e^{15t}+5\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is:

$$\lambda^2 -15 \lambda  = \lambda(\lambda -15) $$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 15, \lambda_2 = 0$.

The corresponding eigenvectors are $v_1 = (4,1), v_2 = (1, 1)$.

This gives,

$$x(t) = c_1 e^{15 t}\begin{bmatrix}
        4 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + c_2\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Note, for the zero eigenvalue, we have $c_2 e^{0 t} = c_2$.

Can you now use the initial condition, $x(0)$, to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ and finish it off?

**Update**

You should get $c_1 = -5, c_2 = -4$ and you could express the final solution as:

$$x(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1(t) \\
        x_2(t) \\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        4c_1 e^{15 t} + c_2 \\
        c_1 e^{15 t} + c_2
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Note: as an alternate approach, you could have also written it as was expressed above, but just substitute the values $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. This is the form that I assumed would result with the zero eigenvalue. Applying the initial condition, I believe I mistakenly switched the values of c1 and c2 that I solved for: I found c1 to be 5 and c2 to be -14. To find the final answer, these coefficients should be multiplied through, correct? How would you express the final answer in a column vector?

Comment: Great, thank you! Thank makes sense. I just made a few algebra errors there.